# numerals in math mode with newtxmath

Tags: newtxmath, mathdesign, xcharter

`\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` produces a bunch of warnings with newer versions of pdflatex. Namely:

"LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value mc. It should not contain an m!"

So I switched to `newtxmath` instead. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[xcharter]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{XCharter}

\begin{document}
0123456789

$0123456789$
\end{document}
```

The problem with this is that digits formatted in text and math mode are different. How to fix this, so  that math mode also uses `XCarter`? Or, alternatively, how to suppress the warning from `mathdesign`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Reverse the loading order:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[xcharter]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
0123456789

$0123456789$
\end{document}
```

[image]